# Python - understanding XML structure when parsing with minidom

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, minidom

Python and XML beginner, so this may seem a little easy, but it challenges my assumtpions 
I am trying to parse an XML structure like this:

```
<variable ordernumber="175">
        <name>Some_text</name>
        <label>Label text</label>
        <values>
          <value code="5">Five</value>
          <value code="4">Four</value>
          <value code="3">Three</value>
          <value code="2">Two</value>
          <value code="1">One</value>
          <value code="0">Zero</value>
        </values>
      </variable>
```

using minidom.

I am trying to extract the texts out of the `name`, `label` and `field` elements:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as md
dom = md.parse(input_file)
root = dom.documentElement
for var in dom.getElementsByTagName('variable'):
    var_name=var.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    var_label=var.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    var_values_list=var.getElementsByTagName('value')
    for var_value in var_values_list:
        print (var_name,var_label,var_values)
```

This is working fine, but there is one thing I do not understand:
Why isn't it possible to get the `var_name` like this:

```
var_name=var.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].nodeValue
```

Why is the `'Some_text'` a child of `<name\>` ? Why isn't it the `nodeValue` ? What would be a `nodeValue` in this context ?
Of course, the same goes for `<label\>` and `<value\>`

Comment: As noted by Michael Kay, the `nodeValue` property of a DOM Element is null by design. That is just how it is. I think you should try ElementTree instead. That API is more straightforward. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad design, but in the DOM, the nodeValue property of an element is null. See for example https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodevalue.asp

There are many better-designed and more modern tree models for XML than DOM, but I don't know if there's anything available in the Python world.